# How to debug why I'm getting a 500 in my ASP.Net project after it's deployed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 solution with 2 projects it in. Let's call it `MySolution` and the 2 projects `Foo` and `Bar`.

It's been running for awhile now in Azure without problem. I've done some pretty big changes over the last month in a branch and am now looking to deploy it. Individually, both `Foo` and `Bar` are functioning correctly when I launch them locally.

My solution is set to launch `Current Selection` when I startup a project, so I'm working on each project separately.

`Foo` is the root of my site, so say http://www.mycompany.com.
`Bar` is set to handle the route of http://www.mycompany.com/r/

I thought everything was going OK, but when I deployed it to my Azure staging environment tonight, the root site loads fine. But when I tried to launch `Bar` by going into the `/r/` sub directory, I get a 404.

I then changed my web.config to have `customErrors=Off` and redeployed. I'm not getting a `HTTP 500` for any page in project `Bar`.

[image]

I don't even know where to begin to debug why this is happening and would love to get pointers on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Can you set *CustomErrors="Off"* in the *Web.config*?

Comment: Just changed it to "Off" and am now getting an HTTP 500 error.  Updated my original post with this info. Still stuck on how to debug this 500.

Comment: So you still can't see the stack trace on the yellow screen?  Also, is it the error 500 (exception) or 404 (not found)?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the 500 error. It's an `Internal server error`, no exception details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log into your Windows Azure VM so you can investigate the root cause of your problem. If you look at application section of event log, you should see the exception and the details of the issue. Copy and paste them here so we can help you further.

Comment: This helped me figure out it was DLL references that were missing. I changed "Copy Local" to "True" for the offending ones and that got rid of the HTTP 500 error. However, it brought up a new issue with web.config, but I'll open a separate question for that.